# Using one domain for pages hosted at two different places

Tags: web, subdomain, jekyll, github-pages, squarespace

I am using Squarespace to host a portfolio site at http://chasem.co. I am also building a personal landing using Jekyll and Github Pages. I want to set this up in a kind of weird way. Here's what I want:

The domain (chasem.co) should point to the landing page hosted on Github using Jekyll. However, I still want to use the the portfolio pages at Squarespace, which  are at chasem.co/photos and chasem.co/design. The page at chasem.co will have links to these pages.

Is this possible? Basically I want to use the root of the domain for a page hosted at one place, and then directories of that URL for pages hosted elsewhere.

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a network genius but I think that your setup will be hard to get working.

The alternative idea is to use a subdomain for your photos and design sections.

- pointing DNS to chasem.co at github + CNAME file in your user repository github.com/userName/userName.github.io
- pointing DNS to photos.chasem.co and design.chasem.co at Squarespace

Comment: Thought about that, but there are 2 problems. 1) I don't want the current links to /photos and /design to break and 2) I don't know is Squarespace will let me configure two different subdomains for specific pages on the site.